# Passing props to open modal in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

So i try to open modal using props from react js..., i try to console log, i found that the props is passed but the modal component is not open.. here is my try:

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
const openModal = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  };
const handleLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    openModal();
  
  };


<div>
      {/* container */}
      <div className="bg-gradient-to-r from-yellow-500 block h-screen items-center justify-center p-4 pt-32 md:flex">
        {<WarnModal props={open} />}
        {/* login.card */}
        <div className=" bg-no-repeat bg-left bg-image flex flex-col items-center max-w-screen-lg overflow-hidden rounded-lg shadow-lg text-white w-full md:flex-row">
          {/* logo */}
          <div className="backdrop-blur-sm backdrop-filter flex flex-col items-center justify-center p-4 text-dark w-full md:w-1/2"> </div></div>
```

here is whats looks like on the modal component:

```
const WarnModal = ({ props }) => {
  console.log("props", props);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const showModal = () => {
    setOpen(props);
  };
  const cancelButtonRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <Transition appear={true} show={open} as={Fragment}>
      <Dialog
        as="div"
        className="relative z-10"
        initialFocus={cancelButtonRef}
        onClose={setOpen}
      >
        <Transition.Child
          as={Fragment}
          enter="ease-out duration-300"
          enterFrom="opacity-0"
          enterTo="opacity-100"
          leave="ease-in duration-200"
          leaveFrom="opacity-100"
          leaveTo="opacity-0"
        >
          <div className="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-500 bg-opacity-75 transition-opacity" />
        </Transition.Child>

        <div className="fixed inset-0 z-10 overflow-y-auto">
          <div className="flex min-h-full items-end justify-center p-4 text-center sm:items-center sm:p-0">
            <Transition.Child
              as={Fragment}
              enter="ease-out duration-300"
              enterFrom="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
              enterTo="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
              leave="ease-in duration-200"
              leaveFrom="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
              leaveTo="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
            >
              <Dialog.Panel className="relative transform overflow-hidden rounded-lg bg-white text-left shadow-xl transition-all sm:my-8 sm:w-full sm:max-w-lg">
                <div className="bg-white px-4 pt-5 pb-4 sm:p-6 sm:pb-4">
                  <div className="sm:flex sm:items-start">
                    <div className="mx-auto flex h-12 w-12 flex-shrink-0 items-center justify-center rounded-full bg-red-100 sm:mx-0 sm:h-10 sm:w-10">
                      <ExclamationTriangleIcon
                        className="h-6 w-6 text-red-600"
                        aria-hidden="true"
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div className="mt-3 text-center sm:mt-0 sm:ml-4 sm:text-left">
                      <Dialog.Title
                        as="h3"
                        className="text-lg font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900"
                      >
                        Account Not Found
                      </Dialog.Title>
                      <div className="mt-2">
                        <p className="text-sm text-gray-500">
                          Please Make Sure You Have Entered The Correct Username
                          or Password that you used to register. Otherwise
                          change your password if you have forgotten it.
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="bg-gray-50 px-4 py-3 sm:flex sm:flex-row-reverse sm:px-6">
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="inline-flex w-full justify-center rounded-md border border-transparent bg-red-600 px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-red-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-red-500 focus:ring-offset-2 sm:ml-3 sm:w-auto sm:text-sm"
                    onClick={() => setOpen(false)}
                  >
                    Okay
                  </button>
                </div>
              </Dialog.Panel>
            </Transition.Child>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Dialog>
    </Transition>
  );
};
export default WarnModal;
```

can someone explained to me where did i do wrong here, i thinks the props has been pass to the component

Comment: You need to decide which component will be responsible for keeping the state of being `open` - implementing it in both is a recipe for confusion and repetition. Also usually you don't make a prop named `props`, you would call it something relevant to the component itself, like (in the case of the higher-level component implementing the `open` state) `isOpen`, or `onOpen` in the case of an event handler.

Comment: @Derek maybe any suggestion on that?

Comment: Done, thanks a lot, i finally get what u say @Derek